# Python tkinter coding a sierpinski triangle in an objective orientated method

Tags: python, class, recursion, tkinter

Hi I'm a complete newbie to python&programming.
Currently I am learning objective orientated programming and recursion.

I am to code a Sierpinski Triangle in an object orientated method.

```
from tkinter import *
from math import *
tk=Tk()
tk.title("Fractal")
canvas=Canvas(tk,width=512,height=600,bg="white")
canvas.pack()

class Triangle:
    def __init__(self,canvas):
        self.canvas=canvas
        self.btn=Button(tk,text="Draw",command=self.draw)
        self.btn.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.label=Label(tk,text="Level")
        self.label.pack()
        self.level=Entry(tk,width=3,justify=CENTER)
        self.level.insert(INSERT, "1")
        self.level.pack()

    def draw(self):
        canvas.create_rectangle(0,0,512,500,fill="white")
        level=int(self.level.get())
        triangle_hieght+int(round(512*sqrt(3.0)/2.0))
        recursion(self.canvas,level,0,triangle_height,256,0,512,triangle_height)

def recursion(canvas,level,x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3):
#I am having a problem with this part of the code


triangle=Triangle(canvas)
```

This is the code that I have written so far, and I have a problem writing the recursive function. I cannot think of a way to define the function, and I need some help.

Comment: try `turtle` module  - it is easier. You can draw `turtle.forward(100)` and turn `turtle.left(90)`

Comment: btw: If you try object orientated programming then `tk=Tk()` should be inside class too.

Comment: I'm trying object orientated programming but I can't find a clue... help

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember Sierpinski triangle recursion but i would start like this

**EDIT:** now it is full working example

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title("Fractal")

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=512, height=600, bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        #self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 512, 500, fill="white")

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Draw", command=self.draw)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Level")
        self.label.pack()

        self.level = tk.Entry(self, width=3, justify=tk.CENTER)
        self.level.insert(tk.INSERT, "1")
        self.level.pack()

        self.mainloop()        

    def draw(self):
        # clear canvas
        self.canvas.delete("all")

        level = int(self.level.get())
        height = int(round(512*math.sqrt(3.0)/2.0))

        self.recursion(level, 0, height, 256, 0, 512, height)

    def recursion(self, level, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
        print("level:", level)

        if level <= 1:
            #print("   draw element")
            self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            self.canvas.create_line(x2, y2, x3, y3)
            self.canvas.create_line(x3, y3, x1, y1)
        else:
            #print("   recursion")
            level = level - 1

            middle_x1 = (x1 + x2)/2
            middle_y1 = (y1 + y2)/2

            middle_x2 = (x2 + x3)/2
            middle_y2 = (y2 + y3)/2

            middle_x3 = (x3 + x1)/2
            middle_y3 = (y3 + y1)/2

            self.recursion(level, x1, y1, middle_x1, middle_y1, middle_x3, middle_y3)
            self.recursion(level, middle_x1, middle_y1, x2, y2, middle_x2, middle_y2)
            self.recursion(level, middle_x3, middle_y3, middle_x2, middle_y2, x3, y3)

# create and start main window
MainWindow()
```

**EDIT:** small modification - create smaller canvas with margin

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import tkinter as tk
import math

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title("Fractal")

        self.width = 512
        self.height = int(round(self.width*math.sqrt(3.0)/2.0))
        self.margin = 10

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.width+(2*self.margin), height=self.height+(2*self.margin), bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Draw", command=self.draw)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Level")
        self.label.pack()

        self.level = tk.Entry(self, width=3, justify=tk.CENTER)
        self.level.insert(tk.INSERT, "1")
        self.level.pack()

        self.mainloop()        

    def draw(self):
        # clear canvas
        self.canvas.delete("all")

        level = int(self.level.get())

        x1 = self.margin + 0 
        y1 = self.margin + self.height
        x2 = self.margin + self.width/2
        y2 = self.margin + 0
        x3 = self.margin + self.width
        y3 = self.margin + self.height

        self.recursion(level, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

    def recursion(self, level, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
        print("level:", level)

        if level <= 1:
            #print("   draw element")
            self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            self.canvas.create_line(x2, y2, x3, y3)
            self.canvas.create_line(x3, y3, x1, y1)
        else:
            #print("   recursion")
            level = level - 1

            middle_x1 = (x1 + x2)/2
            middle_y1 = (y1 + y2)/2

            middle_x2 = (x2 + x3)/2
            middle_y2 = (y2 + y3)/2

            middle_x3 = (x3 + x1)/2
            middle_y3 = (y3 + y1)/2

            self.recursion(level, x1, y1, middle_x1, middle_y1, middle_x3, middle_y3)
            self.recursion(level, middle_x1, middle_y1, x2, y2, middle_x2, middle_y2)
            self.recursion(level, middle_x3, middle_y3, middle_x2, middle_y2, x3, y3)

# create and start main window
MainWindow()
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you have the same code duplicated? If one block of code doesn't work, delete it.

Comment: both code work - but there is modification to show OP how he could change it to get smaller canvas. OP as beginner can compare both code and learn something.

Comment: If that's the case, you should explain that in the answer. It's really hard to understand why both codes are there, and comparing them line-by-line to find that "small modification" is almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

```
import tkinter as tk
import math

class MainWindow(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.title("Fractal")

        self.width = 512
        self.height = int(round(self.width*math.sqrt(3.0)/2.0))
        self.margin = 10

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.width+(2*self.margin), height=self.height+(2*self.margin), bg="white")
        self.canvas.pack()

        self.btn = tk.Button(self, text="Draw", command=self.draw)
        self.btn.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="Level")
        self.label.pack()

        self.level = tk.Entry(self, width=3, justify=tk.CENTER)
        self.level.insert(tk.INSERT, "1")
        self.level.pack()

        self.mainloop()        

    def draw(self):
        # clear canvas
        self.canvas.delete("all")

        level = int(self.level.get())

        x1 = self.margin + 0 
        y1 = self.margin + self.height
        x2 = self.margin + self.width/2
        y2 = self.margin + 0
        x3 = self.margin + self.width
        y3 = self.margin + self.height

        self.recursion(level, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3)

    def recursion(self, level, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
        print("level:", level)

        if level <= 1:
            #print("   draw element")
            self.canvas.create_line(x1, y1, x2, y2)
            self.canvas.create_line(x2, y2, x3, y3)
            self.canvas.create_line(x3, y3, x1, y1)
        else:
            #print("   recursion")
            level = level - 1

            middle_x1 = (x1 + x2)/2
            middle_y1 = (y1 + y2)/2

            middle_x2 = (x2 + x3)/2
            middle_y2 = (y2 + y3)/2

            middle_x3 = (x3 + x1)/2
            middle_y3 = (y3 + y1)/2

            self.recursion(level, x1, y1, middle_x1, middle_y1, middle_x3, middle_y3)
            self.recursion(level, middle_x1, middle_y1, x2, y2, middle_x2, middle_y2)
            self.recursion(level, middle_x3, middle_y3, middle_x2, middle_y2, x3, y3)
```

For to create and start the main window:

```
MainWindow()
```